# Excluding "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog" in pg_dump

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to have the "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog" directive excluded in the result of a pg_dump?

`pg_dump -Fp -O 1.2.0 > /directory/1.2.0.sql`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use `sed` to comment that specific line out:

```
pg_dump -Fp -O 1.2.0 | \
sed -e 's/CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql/-- CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql/g' \
 > /directory/1.2.0.sql
```